# What is [] (list constructor) in Haskell?

Tags: list, data-structures, haskell, types

I'm Having problems understanding functors, specifically what a *concrete* type is in LYAH. I believe this is because I don't understand what `[]` really is.

```
fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

1. Is `[]`, a type-constructor? Or, is it a value constructor?
2. What does it mean to have the type of: `[] :: [a]`?
3. Is it like `Maybe` type-constructor, or `Just` value constructor?
4. If it is like `Just` then how come `Just` has a signature like `Just :: a -> Maybe a` rather than `Just :: Maybe a`, in other words why isn't `[]` typed `[] :: a -> [a]`
5. [LYAH](http://www.learnyouahaskell.com) says this as it applies to functors: *Notice how we didn't write instance Functor [a] where, because from `fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`, we see that the f has to be a type constructor that takes one type. `[a]` is already a concrete type (of a list with any type inside it), while `[]` is a type constructor that takes one type and can produce types such as `[Int]`, `[String]` or even `[[String]]`.* I'm confused though the type of `[]` implies it is like a literal for `[a]` what is LYAH trying to get at?

Comment: And if you want something of type a -> [a], there is the funny looking (:[]) function.

Comment: ^ Or you could use `return` (or `pure` or others) :D

Comment: @DanielVelkov: `:[]` is `:` partially applied to `[]` using the section syntax, just to be clear.

Answer (score 26):

The type is described (in a GHCI session) as:

```
$ ghci
Prelude> :info []
data [] a = [] | a : [a] -- Defined
```

We may also think about it as though it were defined as:

```
data List a = Nil
            | Cons a (List a)
```

or

```
data List a = EmptyList
            | ListElement a (List a)
```

**Type Constructor**

`[a]` is a polymorphic data type, which may also be written `[] a` as above. This may be thought about as though it were `List a`

In this case, `[]` is a *type constructor* taking one type argument `a` and returning the type `[] a`, which is also permitted to be written as `[a]`.

One may write the type of a function like:

```
sum :: (Num a) => [a] -> a
```

**Data Constructor**

`[]` is a *data constructor* which essentially means "empty list." This data constructor takes no value arguments.

There is another data constructor, `:`, which prepends an element to the front of another list. The signature for this data constructor is `a : [a]` - it takes an element and another list of elements and returns a resultant list of elements.

The `[]` notation may also be used as *shorthand* for constructing a list. Normally we would construct a list as:

```
myNums = 3 : 2 : 4 : 7 : 12 : 8 : []
```

which is interpreted as

```
myNums = 3 : (2 : (4 : (7 : (12 : (8 : [])))))
```

but Haskell permits us also to use the shorthand

```
myNums = [ 3, 2, 4, 7, 12, 8 ]
```

as an equivalent in meaning, but slightly nicer in appearance, notation.

**Ambiguous Case**

There is an ambiguous case that is commonly seen: `[a]`. Depending on the context, this notation can mean either "a list of `a`'s" or "a list with exactly one element, namely `a`." The first meaning is the intended meaning when `[a]` appears within a *type*, while the second meaning is the intended meaning when `[a]` appears within a *value*.

Comment: Should that be `sum :: (Num a) => [a] -> a` (with a **->**)?

Comment: Is it same `[a]` with `[] a` when it is used in type signature?

Answer (score 16):

1. It's (confusingly, I'll grant you) syntactically overloaded to be both a type constructor and a value constructor.
2. It means that (the value constructor) `[]` has the type that, for all types `a`, it is a list of `a` (which is written `[a]`). This is because there is an empty list at every type.
3. The value constructor `[]` isn't typed `a -> [a]` because the empty list has no elements, and therefore it doesn't need an `a` to make an empty list of `a`'s. Compare to `Nothing :: Maybe a` instead.
4. LYAH is talking about the type constructor `[]` with kind `* -> *`, as opposed to the value constructor `[]` with type `[a]`.

Comment: It may be helpful to know that as a type, `[a]` is syntactic sugar for `[] a`, which looks more like how things are normally done for higher kinded types.

Answer (score 9):

1. it is a type constructor (e.g. [Int] is a type), and a data constructor ([2] is a list structure).
2. The empty list is a list holding any type
3. [a] is like Maybe a, [2] is like Just 2.
4. [] is a zero-ary function (a constant) so it doesn't have function type.

Comment: I *really* like the wording in 4. I think it took the combination of your answer to 4 and Doug's answer to 3 to get this into my head! So `Nothing :: Maybe a`, and `[] :: [a]` are the empty-constructors. `[a]` is also the analog to `Maybe a` because both are value constructors for values (discrete from Nothing). Conclusion, I was confused by `[]`, because `[]` essentially overlaps the Data-constructor of list with data-constructor of an Array's Nothing, where as `Maybe a` has two separate constructors. Am I correct?

Answer (score 8):

Just to make things more explicit, this data type:

```
data List a = Cons a (List a) 
            | Nil
```

...has the same structure as the built-in list type, but without the (nicer, but potentially confusing) special syntax. Here's what some correspondences look like:

- `List` = `[]`, type constructors with kind `* -> *`
- `List a` = `[a]`, types with kind `*`
- `Nil` = `[]`, values with polymorphic types `List a` and `[a]` respectively
- `Cons` = `:`, data constructors with types `a -> List a -> List a` and `a -> [a] -> [a]` respectively
- `Cons 5 Nil` = `[5]` or `5:[]`, single element lists
- `f Nil = ...` = `f [] = ...`, pattern matching empty lists
- `f (Cons x Nil) = ...` = f [x] = ...`, pattern matching single-element lists
- `f (Cons x xs) = ...` = `f (x:xs) = ...`, pattern matching non-empty lists

In fact, if you ask ghci about `[]`, it tells you pretty much the same definition:

```
> :i []
data [] a = [] | a : [a]           -- Defined in GHC.Types
```

But you can't write such a definition yourself because the list syntax and its "outfix" type constructor is a special case, defined in the language spec.

Comment: Could you explain more about the last part `a:[a]` rather than `a:[]` is the empty list `[]` typed `[a]`, the first part of the definition `data [] = [] | a : [a]`, would leave me to believe it is `[]`. Does `[]`, also suffice the requirement for `[a]`?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. In `a:[a]`, `:` is defining the data constructor (like `Cons`), and `[a]` is specifying the type of an argument to the constructor (like `List a`). In the first part of the definition, `[]` is a data constructor with no arguments, like `Nil`. Both parts produce values of type `[a]`, because that's exactly what is being defined!

Comment: Perhaps what's tripping you up is that *data constructors* don't have to take parameters representing all (or any) of the parameters to the *type constructor*? In `data Either a b = Left a | Right b`, the data constructor `Left a` still creates a value of type `Either a b`, even though there's no `b` to be had. Same goes for `Nothing` and `[]`. You could even have something like `data NoValue a b c d e f = Lonely`. Even though it holds no values, `Lonely` is still haunted by the specter of all those type parameters, keeping it distinct from any `Lonely`s with different types.